# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound

Tags: sql, spring-mvc

getting errors from DAOImpl when I try to get all the cart items that equal to one userId. how do I fix this issue?? thanks for your help.

Here is my ProductDAOImpl.java

```html
@Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Cart> getCartItems(long userId) {
        
        // get the current hibernate session
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                
        // create a query
        Query<Cart> theQuery = 
                currentSession.createQuery("from Cart as c where c.user_id= :userId", Cart.class);
        
        // execute query and get result list
        List<Cart> cartItems = theQuery.getResultList();
                
        // return the results       
        return cartItems;
    }
```

Comment: Does adding a space works ? 

from Cart as c where c.user_id = :userId

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parameter setting.

As the query has where clause, you need to set the parameter also.

```
theQuery.setParameter("userId",userId)
```